# Recommended software for communicating / documenting whilst on a bike tour

Tags: gear, communication, software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Going on a long bike tour, want to make a website](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/going-on-a-long-bike-tour-want-to-make-a-website)

I am going on a long bike tour and I intend to blog about it, take photos etc. I will take a tablet pc or netbook with me, and try to use wifi rather than internet cafes. What software do you recommend  for organising photos, backing up photos, blogging, editing for pod-casts and videos, protecting against viruses, and prevention against theft of the device?

Comment: Not sure if this is the best place to ask this question.  Blogging while on a bike trip wouldn't be significantly different from blogging on a hiking trip or blogging in your living room.  Same goes for virus protection, photo/video editing. You might be able to get some useful information pertaining to theft prevention and the type of computer to bring on a bike trip, but the rest of the question doesn't really fit well on this site.

Comment: I've read a couple blogs like this on Crazy Guy on a Bike (http://www.crazyguyonabike.com/). Seems to be a popular place for what you describe...

Comment: Yeah, but I'm asking the question in context of a bike forum, hence its related to a bike trip.

Comment: I've written an iPhone/iPad app for lightweight blogging while on a bike tour called TrackMyTour.  Updates (with optional photo) are posted to a map for your friends and family to follow along.  Check it out at http://trackmytour.com/.

Comment: I think this might belong better on The Great Outdoors.

Comment: try "Everlater"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using [Prey](http://preyproject.com/) for security. It's open-source and covers any sort of device you would possibly be using.

I use a mac and android tablet for my technology needs and don't worry too much about antivirus programs. It really depends on what OS you end up with. For windows I can recommend AVG Free.

I'm a big fan of wordpress for blogging. It is a little work to set up, but afterwards is highly customizable and controllable.

For organizing photos, I have found Picasa to be a nice program, though a bit heavy for my taste. [The Open Project](http://theopenphotoproject.org/) is a new, free way to organize, upload, and publish photos all on the cloud. It does use dropbox, so size might be a problem.

Comment: Prey is good, it is open source 'spy on your own device' software. The opens source is a major plus for any spy software, as I can at least confirm that it only spies on the device when I command it to.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer where I recommended [traveljournal.net](http://www.traveljournal.net) for keeping a website/blogging, but then I saw [your other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/12899/248) and I moved [my answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/12900/248) to there.